# How to close PostgreSQL process in GitLab?

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

`$ [root@gitlab]# gitlab-ctl stop postgresql`

> timeout: run: postgresql: (pid 27881) 13974s

`$ [root@gitlab]# kill -9 27881`

> 

`$ [root@gitlab]# ps -aux | grep 27881`

> 495      27881  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   14:53   0:00 [postgres]

`$ [root@gitlab]# /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/pg_ctl status`

> pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
>   Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
>   own the server process.

`$ [root@gitlab]# whoami`

> root

`$ [root@gitlab]# /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql`

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>     Is the server running locally and accepting
>     connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: `pg_ctl: cannot be run as root` is the message. (and *please* don't use kill -9, it  creates more problems than it solves)

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I have reboot.